# I cannot install any packages using pip version 19.2.3

Tags: python, pip

I'm using Python version 3.8 with pip version 19.2.3. I tried to install a package but they said I needed to use the latest version of pip to install. The only way to get the latest version of pip, I have to install Python 3.9.0. My OS doesn't support Python 3.9.0 so is there any other way to install packages?

Comment: The `pip` version is separate from your `python` version. Try `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try pip3 command

pip3 install package_name

Comment: Okay I will try that